# Facebook Native Android App- Class Name

Tags: android, android-facebook

I've created a Facebook App. It's working fine totally. What I did is, on developers website in Native Android App section I've put a Class Name of MainActivity so that Facebook can launch that class in native linking. Now I'm posting on Facebook with different Activities. Problem I'm facing is, in that Class Name I have only one class which Facebook can launch. When I'm posting from different Activities how can I obtain respective Activity after login/authorizing it so that Facebook can lauch those respective activity ??

Comment: You need to have a common class for Facebook integration have you tried using a static method (i.e. facebook posting method) from the same main class.

Comment: I can't make it common as one activity is about information and other one is a Augmented Reality.